# Oracle: How to execute an insert trigger without delaying the insert response?

Tags: oracle, http, plsql, triggers

The trigger below is delaying my insert response. How can I prevent this?

```
create or replace
TRIGGER GETHTTPONINSERT
BEFORE INSERT ON TABLENAME
FOR EACH ROW 
Declare
  --   
BEGIN
  -- The inserted data is transfered via HTTP to a remote location
END;
```

**EDIT** People are telling me to do batch jobs, but I would rather have the data earlier than having 100% consistency. The advantage of the trigger is that it happens as soon as the data arrives, but I can't afford the insert response delay.

Comment: You should be aware that this transfer is either synchronous, so the system has to wait for the transfer to complete, or asynchronous, which means that the remote location regulary gets out of sync. You can't have it both ways.

Comment: I would be satisfied with an async option, even if I lose some consistency

Comment: I tried the asynchronous HTTP request, but the reponse time still the same

Comment: I was asking myself the same question and I ended up by making the web web service that create a thread for each request and to respond immediately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a perfect solution for this exact situation called Database Change Notification.

You can think of it almost exactly like an async trigger.

You use the DBMS_Change_Notification package to tell oracle which tables to watch and what to do when a change occurs. You can monitor for DML and DDL, you can have Oracle batch the changes (i.e. wait for 10 changes to occur before firing). It will call a sproc with an object containing all the rowids of the changed rows... you can decide how to handle, including calling HTTP. It will not have to finish for the insert to commit.
[Documentation for 10gR2](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_chngnt.htm)

Comment: Thanks! I saw it after your comment on my blog

Answer (score 10):

One approach is to have the trigger create a dbms_job that runs once (each) time to perform the http transfer.  The dbms_job creation is relatively quick and you can think of this as effectively spawning a new thread in parallel.

See http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:7267435205059  for further info - his example deals with sending email, but the idea is the same.

Comment: The Trigger has an advantage of executing earlier, which is important to me.

Comment: if you have sufficient job_queue_processes available the job will be picked up with no significant delay - creating the job from the trigger does participate in the overall transaction however, so the creation of the job will be delayed until the commit (but this is mostly a good thing, since a rollback will not create the job/initiate the transfer)

Comment: If you are on 10G or above you might have a look at the job scheduler before you use dbms_job, I haven't played with it too much yet but there may be more options and it is the replacement for dbms_job. You could also look at using queuing or dbms_pipe to set up a process to handle the request almost instantly.

Comment: @Ethan - AQ and pipe are certainly other options.  Be careful with dbms_scheduler though, I believe in 10g it commits internally as part of its processing and you wouldn't want it in the middle of your transaction.

Comment: Yes, dbms_scheduler does a commit when you SUBMIT the job, dbms_job doesn't. I really think you should not use dbms_scheduler in this case. See also http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:25405608521707#75146917178353

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you could create a local table that store the info do you have to transfer, and create a job that executes every X minutes. The job read from the table, transfer all the data and delete the transfered data from the table.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't it possible to use the Oracle replication options? You send your inserted data via http to a remote location in an after or before statement trigger. What will happen when there is a rollback? Your hhtp send message will not be rollbacked so you have inconsistent data.

Comment: Inconsistent data is not a problem on my scenario

Comment: Which kind of communication Oracle replication requires? Will it work over the internet or it requires a VPN?

Comment: You can use Oracle Streams to sync two or more databases that are geoghraphically separated, the internet will be used.

Answer (score 0):

well obviously, you could prevent the delay by removing the Trigger....
Else, the trigger will ALWAYS  be executed before your insert, thats what the TRIGGER BEFORE INSERT  is made for.

Or maybe you could give us more details on what you need exactly?

Comment: and if the trigger was changed to AFTER insert? would it solve my problem?
I need to transfer all data that is inserted in my table to a remote location which has an HTTP interface

Comment: Well, since the HTTP thing would be triggered AFTER the insert, the insert wont be delayed anymore by the HTTP request.
So it could be worth a try.

Comment: The AFTER trigger would not be any better. So the row is inserted, but not commited, what's the advantage of that?

Comment: @Jader Dias, What didn't work? It didn't send data via HTTP, there was some kind of error or the performance didn't improve?

Comment: The insert time didn't lower to the same response time it had before the creation of the trigger.

Comment: In other words, the insert is waiting for the HTTP request to complete.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting to this question after 2020, look at DBMS_CQ_NOTIFICATION:

https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/arpls/DBMS_CQ_NOTIFICATION.html